# Deeply understanding the cost of AMI in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I saw some articles like this: [Cost of storing AMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650697/cost-of-storing-ami) and
I am still not sure about the pricing of AMI.

1. I read that you pay only for the bits to create the AMI - how can I know how much bits were used and how much each bit costs?
2. I read that you pay for the storage of it in S3 - I can't find AMIs in my S3 buckets, does the S3 storage saves automatically the AMIs? If yes, where can I find it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: read this https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=124198

Comment: you pay for the storage costs for the size of the AMI you make.  For an EBS backed type this will be the size of the disk.  The AMI are stored in an S3 service which can be accessed by aws cli ec2 commands or in the console ec2 dashboard